# Oracle: Cursor in a Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, package

Please help me with my Oracle procedure question. In my package I have a procedure and I want to declare a cursor which uses dynamic queries.

```
type DocList IS REF CURSOR;
curDocList DocList;
.
.
.
OPEN curDocList FOR v_sql;   --v_sql has dynamic sql
...
FOR recDocStatusList IN curDocList 
      LOOP
```

When I am trying to use - FOR recDocStatusList IN curDocList it is giving me the error: [Error] PLS-00221 (2262: 34): PLS-00221: 'CURDOCLIST' is not a procedure or is undefined.

Please help me correcting the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to iterate the cursor, you can perform it without using a FOR loop.

Option 1:

```
  LOOP
    FETCH curDocList INTO recDocStatusList;
    EXIT WHEN curDocList%NOTFOUND;
    ...
  END LOOP;
```

Option 2:

```
FETCH curDocList INTO recDocStatusList;
WHILE (curDocList%FOUND)
LOOP
    ...
    FETCH curDocList INTO recDocStatusList;
END LOOP;
```

A few annotations:

- Remember to declare recDocStatusList at first.
- Both options are following the OPEN ... FOR line.
- Don't forget to CLOSE the cursor at the end.

Comment: Thanks Neria. In the first place, the compile error is saying 'CURDOCLIST' is not a procedure. So will the above change of looping style help?

Comment: Yes, the exception description doesn't properly reflect the cause. As Tom Kyte said in [this article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:66892450922230), "you can only loop over unopened cursors implicitly", and since a REF CURSOR should be opened, it wouldn't work. "ref cursors are ALWAYS explicit cursors".

Comment: Yep, and therefore you should also FETCH and CLOSE the cursor explicitly. Hence, in my examples I fetched it. Don't forget to close it after the loop.

Comment: Ok I will try...a quick question. I haven't declared recDocStatusList. Is this correct: "recDocStatusList DocList" in declaration

Comment: You haven't post it, but it should be a record of the v_sql ROWTYPE. Edit: Nope, it's incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Neria. That did work!!! Any idea how to print the v_sql while just trying to execute the procedure.

Comment: Print the v_sql's rows or the query itself?